# how to convert unixtimestamp to mysql date format

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I'm writing code to subtract two dates. It is for a contract type thingy, where user gets to see the number of days left for his contract to complete. Something like `start_date_time="today"` and `end_date_time=y`  where the value of `y` is retrieved from the database (DATETIME type). It is in the mysql datetime format (`yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`).

```
<?php
include_once '../include/connections.php';
$id =$_REQUEST['uid'];
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE uid  = '$id'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $test[14];
echo "<br /><br />";
$today=time();
$enddate=strtotime('$test[14]');
$timediff = $enddate - $today;
$days=intval($timediff/86400);
$remaining=$timediff%86400;
$hours=intval($remaining/3600);
$remaining=$remaining%3600;
$mins=intval($remaining/60);
$secs=$remaining%60;
echo "<br>".$days.' days '.$hours.' hours '.$mins.' minutes and '.$secs.' seconds.';
?>
```

When I `echo $test[14];`, I get the date and time as stored in the database which is 
(`2012-09-26 00:00:00`)

When i `echo $today;` then i get it in this format `1348381896`. Now, how do i convert this format to the one retrieved from the db so that i can subtract the 2 dates and get the number of days and time left?

Comment: PHP v5.6 generates from timestamp 1540426286647 -> 50784-03-01 but should be 2018-10-25. When using date('Y-m-d', $lastmodifieddate_ts);

Answer (score 4):

You can use these 2 functions to convert dates to each other,

Use this for timestamp to MySQL datetime:

```
$timestamp = '1348381896';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
echo $date;
```

Use this one for MySQL datetime to timestamp:

```
$date = '2012-09-26 00:00:00';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo $timestamp;
```

Also if you are willing to Subtract your dates in MySQL side, you can use the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and or [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) functions:

Also you can work with timestamps in MySQL too, using [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) functions ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) classes for this:-

```
$today = new DateTime();

$mysqlDate = "2012-12-15 13:40:20"; //for example
// To match your code this would be $mysqlDate = $test[14];
$mysqlFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($mysqlFormat, $mysqlDate);
$diff = $today->diff($endDate);
echo "You have {$diff->d} days, {$diff->h} hours and {$diff->m} minutes left";
```

This will give the following output:-

> You have 22 days, 6 hours and 5 minutes left

(This will change depending on when you run the code).

`$diff` is an instance of [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval).

date formats acceptable to DateTime::createFromFormat() can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php